# Missing crucial steps in Fischer Algebra proof on class equation of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

I have the following Proposition in Fischer's Algebra

> **Proposition**: Let $G$ be a group and $\alpha: G \times M \to M$ a $G$-Action on the finite set $M$. Let $a_1, \dots , a_r$ be a representatives system of the $G$-Orbits then we have $$|G|=\sum_{i=1}^r[G:G_{a_i}] $$

Corollarly he introduces the Class equations of groups

> **Prop2**: Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $Z(G)$ denote the center of $G$ and let $x_1, \dots , x_k$ be the representatives of the $G$-Orbits with *several elements* of the conjugation, then $$|G|=|Z(G)| + \sum_{i=1}^k[G:Z_G(a_i)] $$

---

**My problems**:
Here is what I understand:

I know that that Prop2 should follow immediately from the proposition if we consider a group action $G$ on itself by conjugation, that is $\alpha:G \times G \to G$ by $\alpha(g,a_i)=ga_ig^{-1}$

Then we have by definition $Z_G(a_i)=G_{a_i}$

Furthermore if I force the orbit to consist only of one element I obtain that $$ Ga=\lbrace a \rbrace \iff gag^{-1}=a \iff ga=ag \iff a \in Z(G)$$ Which shows that the center of $G$ consists precisely of the $G$-Orbits with one element.

I don't understand how to proceed from here and why Fischer immediately manages to deduce Prop2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it will be more clear to write down the generalized class equation in place of your first proposition (though what I'm about to write is equivalent).

I will use the notation $$(g,x)\mapsto g.x$$ for the action of $g$ on $X$. For $x\in X$, I'll write $G.x$ for the orbit of $x$, $G_x$ for the stabilizer of $x$, and $X^G=\{x\in X\mid $g.x=x$\mbox{ for all }g\in G\}$ for the set of invariants under this action. Note that we have
$$|G.x|=1\Leftrightarrow x\in X^G.$$

**Proposition:** Let $G$ act on a finite set $X$, and $S$ a set of representatives of the nontrivial orbits (i.e. orbits of size >1). Then,
$$|X|=|X^G|+\sum_{x\in S}[G:G_x]$$

*proof:* Since $X^G$ consists of all elements $x\in X$ such that $|G.x|=1$ and the nontrivial orbits are precisely the $G.x$, $x\in S$, we have $X=X^G\sqcup\left(\bigsqcup_{x\in S} G.x\right)$ where $\sqcup$ denotes disjoint union. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
|X|&=|X^G|+\sum_{x\in S}|G.x|\\&=|X^G|+\sum_{x\in S}[G:G_x],
\end{align*}
where the last equality uses the equality $|G.x|=[G:G_x]$ (which can be seen immediately by identifying the fibers of the action map $G\to G.x$ as the cosets of $G_x$).

Now apply this to the action of $G$ on itself by conjugation. We have $G^G=Z(G)$ and, for $x\in G$, $G_x=Z_G(x)$.

Comment: I just wanted to comment on that your proof is very well written and clear in its presentation. I wish Fischer would write more like this ;) +1